# Scraper fails on files over ~390KB

Tags: facebook, debugging, web-scraping, facebook-opengraph

Does the Facebook's URL scraper have a size limitation on it? We have several books available on a website. Those that have an HMTL filesize under a certain size (~390KB) get scraped and read properly but the 4 that are larger do not. These larger items get a 200 response code and the canonical URL opens.

All of these pages are built using the same template, the only differences being the size of the content within each book and the number of links each book makes to other pages on the site.

1. click on canonical URL
2. Open Firebug In Firefox or developer tools in Chrome to network tab
   3, The *.html size at >~390KB for the listed failures & <~390K for the successes
3. Click on "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL"
4. Blank page for failures, HTML present for successes

**Failures:**

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Frcg.org%2Fbooks%2Ftapom.html
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Frcg.org%2Fbooks%2Ftbgpu.html
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Frcg.org%2Fbooks%2Fttjc.html
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Frcg.org%2Fbooks%2Ftbdse.html

**Successes:**

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Frcg.org%2Fbooks%2Fthogtc.html
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Frcg.org%2Fbooks%2Faabibp.html
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Frcg.org%2Fbooks%2Ftww.html
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Frcg.org%2Fbooks%2Ftsosw.html
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Frcg.org%2Fbooks%2Fsyottc.html
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Frcg.org%2Fbooks%2Fttigtio.html
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Frcg.org%2Fbooks%2Faadac.html
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Frcg.org%2Fbooks%2Fsiud.html
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Frcg.org%2Fbooks%2Ftuyc.html

Comment: Actually you have the answer in you question (which is quite interesting by the way): tmi for the scraper. Maybe you'd like to file a bug in the [Facebook bug reporting tool](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/) and wait for a reply by Facebook on that matter.

Comment: I tried that page before coming here, since this is community support and not actually FB support. I looked at the FB documentation on submitting a bug, but the link they say to click does not appear for me. I also tried at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create/ but could not get the form to submit without the name of an App.

Comment: I tried to notify FB via https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/. We'll see if that bears any fruit. :)

Comment: Until then I have providet you with another answer. Maybe it'll help in case you have to wait for too long. By the way - the answer from @Igy is actually an answer from Facebook since he is part of the Facebook dev support engineering team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution for your problem might be to check whether a real user or the Facebook bot is visiting your page. If it is the bot, then render only the necessary meta data for it. You can detect the bot via its user agent which according to the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) is:
`"facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"`

The code would look something like this (in PHP):

```
function userAgentIsFacebookBot() {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I used this to trim the content of the four books that failed, and now they load. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this isn't a problem on your side? Last time I checked the scraper requested only the first 4096 bytes of the document, which should always be ample space to retrieve the `<head></head>` section with the meta tags

Comment: I am fairly certain this isn't a problem on my side. The URLs that work use the exact same backend code with no problems. 

When I check the "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" link, I see everything from the <!DOCTYPE> to </html> which is considerably more than 4096 bytes. Where did you find that information?

Comment: if you examine the headers the scraper sends, it includes a range header: `Range: bytes=0-40960` (or did a few months ago when i last checked)